# Linking Qline edit with combo box in qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, qlineedit

I want to load the value of book name to a text box when I select the book Id from the `comboBox`. First I wrote the code for loading Book Ids to `comboBox` from database and it loaded perfectly. This is the method.

```
void FictionSection::loadComboVal()
{
    DatabaseConnection mydb;
    QSqlQueryModel *modl = new QSqlQueryModel();
  dbConOpen();

    QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(mydb.db) ;
    query->prepare(" select material_id from fiction ");
  bool flag = query->exec();

  //assigning the values to a QTableView
  if(flag == true)
  {
      modl->setQuery(*query);
      ui->cmbxId->setModel(modl);

}
  mydb.dbConClose();
}
```

Then I wrote the code for assigning values to `textBox` once the book Id is selected from the `comboBox`. This is the code snippet:

```
// loading book names once user select the book id from combo box
void FictionSection::on_cmbxId_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
    QString value = ui->cmbxId->currentText();
    int id;
    if(!value.isEmpty())
    {
     id = value.toInt();
    }
//Loading book table values to a table

dbC    onOpen();
       QSqlQuery query  ;
       QString ids = QString("values('") + QString::number(id);
       query.prepare(" select material_title from book where material_id = '"+ids+"'");
     bool flag = query.exec();

     //assigning the values to a QTableView
     if(flag == true)
     {
        ui->lneditFicNme->setText(query.value(1).toString());


     }
    dbConClose();

}
```

But then loaded values to `comboBox` are invisible and i can't get any value to textbox as I expected. But no compilation or run-time errors. Book Id is stored as an int and book name as `varchar` in database.

I changed the code as follows:

```
void FictionSection::on_cmbxId_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
    QString value = ui->cmbxId->currentText();
    int id;
    if(!value.isEmpty())
    {
     id = value.toInt();
    }
//Loading book table values to a table

       dbConOpen();
       QSqlQuery query  ;
      // QString ids = QString("values('") + QString::number(id);
       query.prepare(" select material_title from book where material_id = ?");
       query.bindValue(0,id);
     bool flag = query.exec();

     //assigning the values to a QTableView
     if(flag == true)
     {
        ui->lneditFicNme->setText(query.value(1).toString());


     }
     else
     {

         QMessageBox :: critical(this,"Error",query.lastError().text());
     }
    dbConClose();

}
```

Then it gives an error as follows:

```
QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
```

I edited the above code but still I couldn't get the expected outcome.

```
void FictionSection::on_cmbxId_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
    DatabaseConnection con;
     con.dbConOpen();


    QString value = ui->cmbxId->currentText();
    int id;
    if(!value.isEmpty())
    {
     id = value.toInt();
    }
//Loading book table values to a table


       QSqlQuery query  ;

      // QString ids = QString("values('") + QString::number(id);
       query.prepare(" select material_title from book where material_id = :id");
       query.bindValue(":id",id);
     bool flag = query.exec();

     //assigning the values to a QTableView
     if(flag == true)
     {

          while(query.next())
          {

             ui->lneditFicNme->setText(query.value(1).toString());

          }
     }
     else
     {

         QMessageBox :: critical(this,"Error",query.lastError().text());
     }
    con.dbConClose();
}
```

Please help me to solve this. Thank you in advance

Comment: closing brace of `values(` is missing .. if `flag != true` you should check for db errors.

Comment: Also I remember using `values()` when adding values to a db .. not when selecting. But if this query works for you it's fine. It is a good idea to debug-out the final query.

Comment: I dunno to close it correctly. When it's closed it gives an error

Comment: Ah, ok you see. The problems start on a lower level. Check on every action on the db for errors .. including open & close to boil down to what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `QSqlQuery::next()` method to position on valid record.

Comment: no it doesn't say that "not positioned in the valid record." but it says duplicate databse etc. and it doesn't even show combobox values. I changed the code later and i have edited my question above. can you check it please?

Comment: You should use index 0 of `QSqlQuery::value()` method. In your case you could also use `query.value("material_title").toString();`.

Comment: It doesn't work either.Nothing is displayed in the qlineEdit