# Duplicate database connection qt

Tags: c++, qt

This is my databaseconnection.h class

```
#ifndef DATABASECONNECTION_H
#define DATABASECONNECTION_H
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDriver>
#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>



class DatabaseConnection
{
public:
    DatabaseConnection();
    bool dbConOpen();
    void dbConClose();
    QSqlDatabase db;



};

#endif // DATABASECONNECTION_H
```

databaseconnection.cpp

```
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDriver>
#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>
#include <QDebug>

#include "databaseconnection.h"

DatabaseConnection::DatabaseConnection()
{

}

bool DatabaseConnection :: dbConOpen()
{
    db = QSqlDatabase ::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("lms");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("");
    if(!db.open())
    {

    return false;

    }
    else

        return true;


}
void DatabaseConnection :: dbConClose()
{
    QString connection = db.connectionName();
    db.close();
    db = QSqlDatabase();
    db.removeDatabase(connection);
}
```

fictionsection class inherits database class through materials.h class. Then im loading a table records to a qtableview through a button click in fictionsection.cpp class as follows

```
void FictionSection::on_btnLoad_clicked()
{
    DatabaseConnection mydb;
        mydb.dbConOpen();

       //Loading fiction table values to a table

       QSqlQueryModel *modl = new QSqlQueryModel();


       QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(mydb.db) ;
       query->prepare(" select * from fiction");
     bool flag = query->exec();

     //assigning the values to a QTableView
     if(flag == true)
     {
         modl->setQuery(*query);
         ui->tblFiction->setModel(modl);
          ui->tblFiction->show();


     }
    dbConClose();

}
```

When the project is run it gives the following message. But the project run exactly as I wanted.

```
QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.
```

Please help me to solve this and are there any bad effects due to this message. Because Im planning to run my project in Ubuntu after completing the whole implimentation. Currently I use Windows OS.

Comment: i think it is a 'problem' with your code opening a db connection every time you push the button. it should not do any harm but i am sure you could also just open the connection and stay connected untill you quit the application

Comment: Use connection names: `db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "connection_name");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking Qline edit with combo box in qt c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129395/linking-qline-edit-with-combo-box-in-qt-c)

Answer (score 0):

This message is displayed due to opening and closing the database connection unnecessarily. final code should be as follows.

```
void FictionSection::on_btnLoad_clicked()
{
    DatabaseConnection mydb;


       //Loading fiction table values to a table

       QSqlQueryModel *modl = new QSqlQueryModel();


       QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(mydb.db) ;
       query->prepare(" select * from fiction");
     bool flag = query->exec();

     //assigning the values to a QTableView
     if(flag == true)
     {
         modl->setQuery(*query);
         ui->tblFiction->setModel(modl);
          ui->tblFiction->show();


     }


}
```